# Coordinate translation in QGis?

Tags: qgis, translation

Is there a way to apply an arbitrary coordinate translation to a layer in QGis 2.8.2? I have some data sets that are in a truncated coordinate system, and I need to shift them by a certain amount to line up with the real world coordinate system.

Comment: I believe you can do this in the CRS definition by tinkering with the parameters.

Comment: I thought about doing this, but the CRS screen doesn't let me edit the proj+ line. I'll keep looking...thanks!

Comment: I would try affine transformation. v.transform seems to do it and then there should be this http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/qgsAffine/. However, I can't install the latter with the plugin manager. But I am not sure what you mean with arbitrary. Affine is not arbitrary. For more flexible "rubber sheet" warping with warping vectors I would use OpenJUMP.

Comment: There is a plugin called 'vectGeoref' that might help. (I think it is experimental.) I've never used it so I'm not putting this forward as an answer.

Comment: I am working on a site where mine coordinates are state plane coordinates minus 800,000 in X and minus 2,300,000 in Y, so in order to use layers generated in mine coordinates, I need to shift the layer by +800,000 in X and +2,300,000 in Y in order for them to be overlaid properly with layers that are in actual state plane coordinates. Thank you all for your suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

In QGIS, you can take the CRS definition, go to Settings -> Options -> Custom CRS, and paste it there as a new CRS.

If it is a projected CRS like transverse mercator, lambert or albers, you can set or modify the projection with a false Easting `+x_0` or false Northing `y_0`.

For geographic CRS with degrees as units, you can modify the `+towgs84` parameters.

Having saved your custom CRS, you can Rightclick -> `Set Layer CRS` to apply it to your datasource.

Using a plugin for affine transformation might be easier, see

- AffineTransformations
- Vector Bender
- vectorgeoref

plugins. You might have to enable experimental plugins in the settings tab to see and install them.